# Stacking problem with Div and Jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have setup a photo slider on the top of my page, and it seems that it is over-riding my z-index for the drop down menu. Can anyone see why the drop down menu for administration is being hidden behind the picture? Ive tried changing the z-index of divs I thought would be affecting it, but none of my changes seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you specify the positioning of the element when you use z-index. Also, in this case if you change the z-index of your navigational element, you also need to make sure that it is above **all** of the pictures in your photo slider and not just one or some of them.

Just change:

```
<div id="navigation" class="navigation">
```

To:

```
<div id="navigation" class="navigation" style="position:relative; z-index:8;">
```

Or specify

```
position: relative;
z-index: 8;
```

in your style sheet for the navigation element.

See?